# How can you tell if someone is running a decompiled / de-obfuscated version of your code?

Tags: python, security, obfuscation, deobfuscation, pyarmor

I recently used [PyArmor](https://pyarmor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to obfuscate some code. I know that there's no completely fool-proof way to prevent someone from de-obfuscating your code, but is there a way to definitively know whether a user is running the obfuscated or de-obfuscated version?

One idea I considered was to identify certain functions that run at notably different speeds when obfuscated vs. de-obfuscated. In this case, I could send that particular function's execution time to a server that would verify whether the function was run in an obfuscated or a de-obfuscated program. I haven't been able to find any functions that fit the bill though.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: If people de-obfuscate the code, then they will most likely know what you are trying to do, so it won't work. Also, the way the v8 engine works is that is compiles the JS to faster code if it's used a lot, so if the function you are testing is ran a few times, the speed will increase as it gets compiled to be faster. Besides, they could just change the headers, making the speed test useless.

Comment: Thanks for the response - that's good to know. What do you mean by "the headers" though? And do you know if there's an easy way to de-obfuscate PyArmor byte code?

Comment: `I could send that particular function's execution time to a server` Headers are part of a http request. If you sent the information about the function over http, the person who is copying your code can just use a proxy or change the code so it always sends a time that will not get flagged.